# Can the event.detail object contain more than one value? (Vanillatree.js)

Tags: javascript, html, events, tree

While playing around with [Vanillatree.js](https://github.com/finom/vanillatree) I stumbled onto `event.details` and thought of the following:

If you want the selection from the tree to populate a textarea, you could use something like the code below, but what if you want to use something like `label`or `name` instead of `id`?

```
main.addEventListener('vtree-select', function(evt) {
randomtextArea.value = evt.detail.id + ' is selected';
});
```

In my case, each element of the tree looks like this:

```
id:{
attribute1:"value1",
parentId:parentId,
name:name,
id:id
}
```

I think the responsible function in the main js file are:

```
        _dispatch: function( name, id ) {
        var event;
        try {
            event = new CustomEvent( 'vtree-' + name, {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                detail: {id:id}
            });
        } catch(e) {
            event = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
            event.initCustomEvent( 'vtree-' + name, true, true, { id: id });
        }
        ( this.getLeaf( id, name, true ) || this.tree )
            .dispatchEvent( event );
        return this;
    },
```

Even when stuff like `{test:'testtesttest'}` is written inside the details it always passes only the `id` to `event.details`

Am I looking in the wrong place? 
Can the event function only use the name of the object (`id`) and not its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

I made a wrong assumption, the whole object gets referenced with `id`, it is possible to call the other values.

working code:

```
main.addEventListener('vtree-select', function(evt) {
randomtextArea.value = tree.leafs[evt.detail.id].labeling + ' is selected';
});
```